# How to set attribute on a component inside a slot in Vue?

Tags: vue.js, vue-component

### Problem

I have a `BaseFormControl` component which accepts `id` prop. It sets `id` prop value as both `for` attribute value on `<label>` element and `id` attribute value on a given input. As I want `BaseFormControl` to be a generic component re-usable with various input types, I pass the input as a slot. The code for the component below:

```
<script>
export default {
   props: {
     id: {
       type: String,
       required: true
     }
   }
};
</script>

<template>
  <div>
    <label :for="id">
      <slot name="label" />
    </label>
    <slot
      name="input"
      :id="id"
    />
  </div>
</template>
```

The problem with this approach is that `<slot>` doesn't pass any attributes to the slot contents, so `:id` isn't passed to the actual input at all.

So I tried setting it programatically:

```
export default {
   props: {
     id: {
       type: String,
       required: true
     }
   }

   created() {
     let inputSlot = this.$slots.input;
     if (inputSlot) {
       inputSlot[0].data.attrs.id = this.id;
     }
   }
};
```

It works perfectly in some cases (input passed as a slot has `id` attribute set properly in it's HTML), but in others it doesn't. What's especially interesting is that all the input components (what I put in the input slot is another base component, not a generic `<input>` tag) actually have it's `this.$attrs` properly populated with `id`, but sometimes it appears in actual HTML and sometimes it does not.

Can someone explain me that behavior, tell me what I'm doing wrong and how to solve that case?

### Pen

I created a [pen](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/RJZZaZ) to illustrate the concepts. The only problem is in the pen everything works fine. In my app out of 2 selects on the page, only 1 has `id` set properly - the other one is rendered without `id` at all (though `id` is set in it's `this.$attrs`).

Answer (score 2):

> The problem with this approach is that  doesn't pass any attributes to the slot contents,

What yoou are doing is passing  `id` to the slot as slot data. Which means you are creating a [scoped slot](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components-slots.html#Scoped-Slots).

You can access this data in the `BaseFormControl` using the `slot-scope` attribute.

```
<BaseFormControl :id="'myInput'">
  <p slot="label">Input label</p>
  <input slot="input" slot-scope="props" :id="props.id" type="text" placeholder="type anythin">
</BaseFormControl>
```

### PS:

if you are passing `id` as a prop you can directly use it to set the id of the input as below

```
<BaseFormControl :id="'myInput'">
  <p slot="label">Input label</p>
  <input id="myInput" type="text" placeholder="type anythin">
</BaseFormControl>
```

Comment: I agree it would work, but that approach would require me to declare `id` on `<input>` with `slot-scope="props" :id="props.id"`, every single time I'm using `BaseFormControl`. I want to encapsulate all that relation/requirement inside the `BaseFormComponent` to avoid this repetition.

Answer (score 1):

Searching for solutions I've decided that the easiest way is to add "for" attribute for component and forward it to label.

Also I set "id" attribute for slot content manually. This is almost the same way we use `<label>` in HTML.

```html
<!-- component.vue -->
<template>
    <div class="form-group row my-2">
        <label class="col-4 col-form-label" :for="$props.for">{{ label }}</label>
        <div class="col-8" >
            <slot></slot>
        </div>
    </div>
</template>
<script>

export default {
    name: "SettingsRow",
    props: {
        label: {required: true, type: String},
        for: {required: true, type: String}
    }
}
</script>
```

This is how I use this component.

```html
<settings-row label="Choose chromosome" for="someId">
    <select v-model="ch" id="someId">
        <option>X</option>
        <option>Y</option>
    </select>
</settings-row>
```

It looks like all other methods require many unclear attributes for scoped/named slots in component itself and in it usage.